# How to deploy silverlight application in IIS 7.0?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight

I have created a sample silverlight web application and followed the steps given in 
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39169 to deploy. i have copied clientbin folder consisting .xap file and .html and silverlight.js to sampleApp folder in wwwroot and converted it to application in IIS. But when I browse the application, it is not opening and the URL in the browser is coming as "//localhost/sampleApp/" instead of "//localhost/sampleApp/samplepage.html". When I open in content view and rightclick on samplepage.html and browse, it works fine. Can anyone help me where the deployment steps went wrong? I dont want to go to content view always and browse the samplepage.html always. I want this to happen from rightclicking the application and browse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add samplepage.html to the Default Document list for your web application.

Comment: Hi Russell,
It is working now. Thank you for your answer